# Looking to protect outlook data file against theft

Tags: office365

We have an office 365 subscription and we want our users to set up their emails on their personal computers using outlook client so they can save emails more easily compare to using OWA.

But we are worried that if their laptop gets stolen their emails will be stolen too since the outlook data file will be saved on their personal computers.

Is there any way we can protect that data file against possible thefts?

Comment: this question would be better suited for the [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com)

Comment: and if not IS then superuser.com